# downgrading numpy version on google colab

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory, downgrade

I need numpy== 1.18.0 or under 1.20.0, however,  I get error as below:

```
Collecting numpy==1.18
  Using cached numpy-1.18.0.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

what I tried are:

- first I checked the numpy version as below:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

this showed numpy 1.25

- Then, I uninstalled the current version as bellow:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

it said the numpy was successfully uninstalled.

- Then, I installed the desired version
  `pip install numpy==1.18`
  and got the error that I mentioned.
  I again checked the numpy version and it still shows 1.25, although it showed the numpy has been successfully uninstalled!  Also, I tried this process for other under 1.20 numpy versions and the outcome was the same as above!